# Water Jug Problem java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Writing a piece of code for my AI class that's meant to list all the possible states given three jugs for the water jug problem (you can fill any jug, or pour as much as will fit from one into another, or empty any jug, as many times as you want and in any order) starting with empty jugs.

For some reason, after recording 88 seemingly distinct states, the 89th is the same as the first, and I end up running out of space because it loops round.

I think it's something to do with how I check that the states are distinct, but can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

public class AI {
    private static final int[] start=new int[]{0,0,0};
    private static int[] jugs;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        jugs=new int[]{Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]),Integer.parseInt(args[2])};

    String out="";
    out=out.concat("{");
    for (int[] state:addStates(start,new ArrayList<>())) {
        out=out.concat("{"+state[0]+","+state[1]+","+state[2]+"}");
    }
    out=out.substring(0,out.length()-2).concat("}");
    System.out.println(out);

}

private static List<int[]> addStates(int[] start, List<int[]> states) {


    states.add(start);

    int[][] newStates={
            fillA(start),
            fillB(start),
            fillC(start),
            emptyA(start),
            emptyB(start),
            emptyC(start),
            pour(start,0,1),
            pour(start,0,2),
            pour(start,1,0),
            pour(start,1,2),
            pour(start,2,0),
            pour(start,2,1)
    };

    for (int[] child:newStates) {
        if (!has(states,child)) {
            states.addAll(addStates(child,states));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("close");
    return states;
}
private static boolean has(List<int[]> list, int[] e) { //finds out if list contains something with the same values as e
    for (int[] el:list) {
        boolean is=true;
        for(int i=0;i<e.length;i++){
            if (el[i]!=e[i]){
                is=false;
            }
        }
        if(is){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static int[] fillA(int[] state) {
    return new int[]{jugs[0],state[1],state[2]};
} //fills A
private static int[] fillB(int[] state) {
    return new int[]{state[0],jugs[1],state[2]};
} //fills B
private static int[] fillC(int[] state) {
    return new int[]{state[0],state[1],jugs[2]};
} //fills C
private static int[] emptyA(int[] state) {
    return new int[]{0,state[1],state[2]};
} //empties A
private static int[] emptyB(int[] state) {
    return new int[]{state[0],0,state[2]};
} //empties B
private static int[] emptyC(int[] state) {
    return new int[]{state[0],state[1],0};
} //empties C
private static int[] pour(int[] state, int from, int into) {
    int currentInto=state[into];
    int currentfrom=state[from];
    if (currentInto+currentfrom>jugs[into]){
        currentfrom-=(jugs[into]-currentInto);
        currentInto=jugs[into];
    } else {
        currentInto+=currentfrom;
        currentfrom=0;
    }

    int[] newState= new int[3];
    newState[from]=currentfrom;
    newState[into]=currentInto;
    newState[3-from-into]=state[3-from-into];

    return newState;
} //moves as much water from "from" into "into"
```

}

Comment: Solutions don't belong in the question.  Next time, feel encouraged to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used both `states.add(start)` and `states.addAll(addStates(child,states))`, meaning that I added each element a huge number of times. After fixing this, the code worked perfectly fine.